# Can you host multiple tenants on a single ASP.NET application instance over SSL?

Tags: asp.net, iis, ssl, hosting

I have an ASP.NET application that will host multiple tenants (Software-as-a-Service style). Each tenant will have their own domain name (www.mydomain.com, www.yourdomain.com) and their own SSL certificate.

**Is there a way to host the application such that all of the tenants are on the same application *instance*?**

- I know you can have multiple IIS web sites pointing to the same shared location, but that won't work - it's not the same *instance*. That's different *instances* of the same *application*.
- I also know you can use SSL host header mapping with wildcard certificates, but that won't work because all of the tenants would need to be subdomains of the same primary domain - yourdomain.commondomain.com, mydomain.commondomain.com. For the solution to be valid, everyone needs to have their own domain name, not be subdomains. (Ideally each tenant could opt to use an EV cert, too, and you can't have wildcard EV certs.)

Comment: You ever find a solution for this?

Comment: As of today (Dec 4 2008) I have not found a solution that didn't involve decrypting the content before it hit the web server and forwarding on the decrypted (or re-encrypted) request. Unfortunately, for my issue, that sort of solution isn't really an option. So... no solution yet.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that classic SSL requires the certificate to be presented before the web browser has indicated which host it wants to use. You can therefore only configure one certificate per IP/port combination.

There is an extension to TLS called [Server Name Indication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) which allows the browser to indicate which logical server it wants to talk to. This feature is [supported as of IIS 8.0 (Windows Server 2012)](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-server-name-indication-sni-ssl-scalability).

Wildcards work because the certificate *itself* says that it is valid for all servers under that domain.

Answer (score 1):

You constrained to only IIS - or could putting soft/hard proxies or content-switching hardware also be an option?

Thinking that you could terminate the SSL at a proxy or content-switch - then transform the request into your own internal url.

e.g. foo.com/x and bar.com/y get translated into myapp/x and myapp/y respectively under the hood - passing the original hostname in the request headers.